# Google Cloud Function - Storage - Delete Image - "ApiError: Error during request"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

**UPDATED QUESTION**

**The problem is `ApiError: Error during request`**.

Code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const gcs = admin.storage();

export const deleteImage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    return cors(req, res, async () => {

        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const id = req.body.id;
        const name = req.body.name;

        const imageRef = gcs.bucket(`images/${name}`);

        if (!name || !id) {
            return res.status(400).send({message: 'Missing parameters :/'});
        }

        try {
            await imageRef.delete();
            console.log('Image deleted from Storage');
            return res.status(200).send({status: 200, message: `Thank you for id ${id}`});
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error);
            return res.status(500).send({message: `Image deletion failed: ${error}`});
        }

    });
});
```

*And the problem is here*: `await imageRef.delete();`, I get the following error:

> ApiError: Error during request.

I do, indeed, have `admin.initializeApp();` in one of my other functions, so that can't be the issue, unless GCF have a bug.

**More In-Depth Error**:

```
{ ApiError: Error during request.
    at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:187:32)
    at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:131:18)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:496:12
    at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:198:7)
    at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
code: undefined,
errors: undefined,
response: undefined,
message: 'Error during request.' }
```

*(old question removed)*

Answer (score 0):

"Error: Can't set headers after they are sent" means that you tried to send two responses to the client.  This isn't valid - you can send only one response.

Your code is clearly sending two 200 type responses to the client in the event that imageRef.delete() fails and the catch callback on it is triggered.

Also, you're mixing up await with then/catch.  They're not meant to be used together.  You choose one or the other.  Typically, if you're using await for async programming, you don't also use then/catch with the same promise.  This is more idiomatic use of await with error handling:

```
try {
    await imageRef.delete()
    res.status(200).send({status: 200, message: `Thank you for id ${id}`});
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({message: `Image deletion failed: ${err}`});
}
```

Note also that you typically send a 500 response to the client on failure, not 200, which indicates success.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for your response. This are definitely some good improvements to go into my code, however, the primary error still has no solution: `"ApiError: Error during request"` Any ideas behind this?

Comment: Then I would suggest reframing your question with the *shortest possible code in a single file* that demonstrates the problem, so that other issues won't get conflated, and we won't have to take your word that missing code is actually present.